# Ability to get list of ListView items from checked items in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding

I have a list view of two columns. First column is a checkbox and second column is a server value. I want to essentially get a list of all servernames that have a corresponding checkbox in that row after I click a button. How is this possible? Below I was able to get the data bound successfully from my server model and put a checkbox in the first column, but I am stuck.

I am attempting to follow the MVVM pattern, so I have a view-model class that I ideally want to handle this logic and then pass it along after the checked server names are stored in some collection.

## XAML Code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" Margin="8,30,10,68">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Select For Sync">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Pad Name"  
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NodeName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: "but I am stuck", what exactly is the problem? Is there nothing shown in the second column? Does it add only one row? Your code can actually be simplified if each data in `Servers` has a boolean, to store whether or not the checkbox is checked, I have done this before and can provide some sample code if needed.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I want to turn the selected checkboxes into a string collection where each item in the collection is the associated string name in the server column. The data shows in the second column, but I want to grab that data based on what is checked in the first column

Comment: I have done something very similar before, I will try to adapt part of my code to suit your requirement as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll briefly describe the method I used for something similar.

First, for the custom class, it should look something like this:

```
public class Server
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }     //or IsSelected maybe? whichever name you want  
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
}
```

And for your XAML, you could use this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Select For Sync">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Pad Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NodeName}" />
</GridView>
```

Your collection/list which you use to bind to the ListView (`Servers`) should be of data type `Server`, from above. And whenever you need to access the checked boxes and the corresponding rows, it is as simple as:

```
List<Server> checkedRows = Servers.Where(s => s.isChecked).ToList(); //there, you now have a list of checked rows
```

OR if you want the names

```
List<string> nodeNames = Servers.Where(s => s.isChecked).Select(s => s.NodeName).ToList();
```

Comment: For some reason this solution isn't working. I bound a command to print the checkedrows, the function gets called but the list is empty, regardless of what I check.

Comment: The actual property does not get changes in the server object for isChecked

Comment: Your bound ItemsSource, could I see the implementation (if you're using `List<Server> Servers` or something else?). Basically try using `ObservableCollection<T>` [ObservableCollection<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events of the `CheckBox` in your view, you should bind the `IsChecked` property to a boolean property of your `Server` type, i.e. the type `T` in your `IEnumerable<T>` `Servers` source collection:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" Margin="8,30,10,68">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Select For Sync">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Pad Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NodeName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

You could then simply iterate through the records in the `Servers` collection in the view model class and check the property to determine which items that are currently selected:

```
var selectedItems = Servers.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
foreach(var selectedItem in selectedItems)
   ...
```